# react redux state changed to initial after browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am making a `react` app using `redux`. I am going great except one issue.

Whenever I refresh the browser my `state` changed to initial state. Lets say I have a user authenticated and I have set him as `authenticated: true` and after authenticating when I refresh the page the state changed to initial and `authenticated:false` is set.

I am confused why is this happening ?

Can anyone point what might be the issue here

Comment: So where is data supposed to be kept between page reloads?

Comment: I dont know.. everything works fine untill page refresh.. when I refresh the page state goes to initial state.. Any idea where I can store the state after page being reload ?

Comment: Redux store is not persistent. It's your responsibility if you need this feature.  Save it in localStorage, use REST API, ...

Comment: Lets say I am authenticating from facebook.. I am authenticated successfully . After I refresh my browser I am not authenticated anymore.. I have to login again..

Comment: what the guys are trying to tell you is that this is working as intended. Redux store is not persisted between page reloads. Every reload is a brand new app. You will have to create some sort of persistence between the reloads and fetch data from there at the beginning of the process.

Answer (score 7):

Redux stores are not persistent. When the page reloads, all data is initialized again. If you would like to save a piece of your store (or the whole thing) you will need to save it in localstorage, or saving it to your server and making a REST request asking for the data again.
You can use [this package](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage) to save your store into localstorage.

Comment: interesting, I have been doing mostly React Native work with Redux. I suppose there's not really a 'refresh' per se in the mobile world, so I haven't run into this as a problem until I started a web project. Thanks for the info and pointer to the local storage package. ~~